# How to get filed type by reflection at run time?

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism

How to get class type(A1 or A2) of base in test method by reflection at run time ?  I tried `this.getClass().getField("base").getType();` but getType returns declared type, Is there any method can do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Base{

}

public class A1 extends Base{

}

public class A2 extends Base{

}

public abstract class Cmd{
    public Base base;
    public void test(){
        this.getClass().getField("base").getType();
    }

}

public class Cmd1 extends Cmd{
    public Cmd1(Base base){
        this.base = base;

    }
}


public class Cmd2 extends Cmd{
    public Cmd2(Base base){
        this.base = base;
    }
}

Base testBase = new A1();
Cmd myCmd = new Cmd1(testBase);
```

Comment: Why don't you do `base.getClass()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is entirely impossible.

`this.getClass()` would refer to either the object representing your `Cmd1` class, or your `Cmd2` class. However, in either case, the actual field referred to by the name `base` is that `public Base base;` field. And the type of that *FIELD* is `Base` because.. well, it's right there. It doesn't magically change just because this class is subclassed. Reflection represents the class as you typed it, not any particular instance of it.

Once you are talking about a specific instance of `Cmd1` or `Cmd2`, which you are, as there is a `this` reference, you can just dereference your field and check what's actually there: `this.base.getClass()`. Of course, if `this.base` is null, that won't work, and that's the point: the base field COULD reference any instance whose type is `Base` or any subtype thereof, but currently it references nothing, therefore there is no way to answer the question 'what is the specific type of the thing you are referencing'.

Comment: The presence of the classes `Cmd1` and `Cmd2` is a red herring. The decision to pass an `A1` instance where `Base` is required, is made at the `Base testBase = new A1(); Cmd myCmd = new Cmd1(testBase);` place, which could be anywhere in the application. It’s also deciding to construct an instance of `Cmd1` and assign it to a variable of type `Cmd`, but that’s entirely unrelated. There is no connection between `Cmd1` and `A1`. The code could have done `new Cmd2(new A1())` or `new Cmd1(new A2())` instead. We can’t even preclude that some other code in the same runtime does this already.

Comment: Of course it's a red herring, but the question asker seems to think that somehow it's possible to derive A1 from the Base field.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes, your answer is what I want. Thank you!